# How to get the Bootstrap modal without Id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have multiple bootstrap modal in my application and I want to call an same function on each modal `shown.bs.modal` event. I want to do this globally at one place but the thing that bother me is that this event needs an `id` attribute of a particular modal like below:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

I want to know that is there any way to do it globally as whenever some modal shows, then one function call?

Comment: consider using a class name instead of id

Comment: Call using the class .modal because that comes for all modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working great for me.

```
$(window).on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
            //Do what ever you want here...
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('#myModal')` is simply a jQuery selector. Read [more](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) about the jQuery selectors. We can write anything withing `$()` like:

```
$("#myModal")         // Select an element with id "myModal"
$("body > #myModal")  // Select an element with id "myModal" which is a immediate child of the "body" tag
$("#foo .modal")      // Select all elements with a class "modal" which is inside an element with id "foo"
```

So, in Bootstrap, every modal has a class `.modal`, you can simply use that class to attach a global listener:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
});
```

Or, like others have mentioned, you can give a class to all your modal where you want to do some common stuff like `do-common-stuff`:

```
<div class="modal do-common-stuff" id="foo">...</div>
<div class="modal" id="bar">...</div>
<div class="modal do-common-stuff" id="tango">...</div>
```

and later,

```
$('.do-common-stuff').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
});
```

Comment: It works with class name.Actually i just want to know that maybe is there another way to do this. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

You can go with the Class name of model

```
$('.modelClassName').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with class

```
$('.classNameOfModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider accessing through class name. Dot '.' is used for class.

```
$('.myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```